# Spring boot background task

Tags: java, spring

I'm building an online judge. When user post a submission, the controller add the submission to redis. The judger wrote in python fetch it and put the result back to the redis. 
Now I want spring boot get the result and then save it to the database. How can I do it in another process?

Comment: How do you want to do this? Should you have a cron job that checks periodically for new entries in the Redis? Or do you notify the Spring Boot when there is a new entry in Redis, and save that into DB?

Comment: I want to build another process polling the redis. Or notify the Spring Boot when there is a new entry in Redis. Not scheduling.